# How to update mlr3 library in Rstudio

Tags: r, mlr3

I was using mlr3 library from few weeks and now suddenly I am getting the following error:

Loading required package: mlr3
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mlr3’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
namespace ‘data.table’ 1.13.0 is already loaded, but >= 1.13.6 is required
Error: package ‘mlr3’ could not be loaded

I dont know how to update the package because the version 1.13.6 is not available in the Tools menu of R studio.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your R session and then update `data.table` via `install.packages("data.table")`.

Comment: again:   install.packages("data.table")
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages
> install.packages("data.table")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Asad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/data.table_1.14.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2603350 bytes (2.5 MB)
downloaded 2.5 MB

Comment: ‘data.table’ 1.13.0 is already loaded, but >= 1.13.6 is required.. When I try to install data.table, version 1.13.0 is installed while the required version in 1.13.6 or greater

Comment: I also tried to update the data.table with 'update' option in Rstudio but also fails

Comment: when updating, I get the following : Warning message:
replacing previous import ‘vctrs::data_frame’ by ‘tibble::data_frame’ when loading ‘dplyr’

Comment: Please do not comment every output of your tryouts. `data.table` is not loaded by default when starting a new session and it hard to debug your local issues remotely this way. Do the update in the terminal, optimally with `R --vanilla` and things will work. Also it might be beneficial to get more familiar with R and its messages to understand the warnings and errors in the future :)